How does this water canon function?
While idly watching shorts, I came across this one. And after watching it a hundred times, I still don't understand how the water canon functions. I mean, where is the pressure coming from?
The design is so simple that I can't imagine any hidden internal mechanisms causing the pressure. And from outside, I can't see anything to provide the pressure.
Video poster claims it to be a water gun, are they lying? (Maybe it uses chemicals instead of water.)
Where is the required pressure coming from if it is a water gun?
PS: 1. I know it's the internet, which could be fake. If you believe the video is fake, comment that. Don't motion to delete the question if someone has a possible explanation. I will delete the question myself if I get many comments about it being fake and no reason for the canon in 15 days.

I am unsure if this is a SE: Engineering question(I read the help centre post) or if it would be better suited to SE: Physics. If its the latter let me know, I will move the question.

I have no intention of trying something like this, just curiosity. (The help centre had something about that being a no-no for questions)



RHS with an airline connector?

the square contains compressed gas

On the backside I can see a valve assembly, I don't see enough detail but it's likely a connector for compressed air.
Assuming that the mechanism is simple, compress the air in the square part then fill the barrel with plain water. Then actuate the ball-valve between the barrel and the air storage quickly to shoot.

So, its basically an air gun with water instead of pellets? Water itself is not pressurized then?

yeah, the water just sits in the barrel and would poor out if they tipped it down.
